# check if a character within a string is uppercase

Tags: r, uppercase

I have a string

```
x <- "lowerUpper"
```

and want do determine if and which character within this string is an uppercase letter.

I can use `toupper(x) == x`, which tells me if all characters are uppercase, but how do I check if only some (and which) are?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is `gregexpr` to find the position where the character is uppercase

```
unlist(gregexpr("[A-Z]", x))
#[1] 6
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the symbol `\U` to check for uppercase:

```
unlist(gregexpr("\\U", "lowerUpper"))
#[1] 6
```

Answer (score 1):

```
> x <- "lowerUpper"
> sapply(strsplit(x, ''), function(a) which(a %in% LETTERS)[1])
[1] 6
```

or

```
> library(stringi)
> stri_locate_first_regex(x, "[A-Z]")
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to check each letter:

```
which(toupper(strsplit(x,split = "")[[1]])==strsplit(x,split = "")[[1]])
#[1] 6
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a cleaner code version using %in%

```
unlist(strsplit("lowerUpper",'')) %in% LETTERS
```

An advantage here is the return of the logical vector indicating each letter position in the string. This solution works for multiple uppercase letters too, whereas the grep options return only the first match. Lastly, using LETTERS makes for more readable code to my mind.